# Cocoa: determine network availability on wake

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, reachability

I'm writing a Cocoa OS X application that needs to perform different actions depending on whether or not there is internet connectivity when the system wakes from sleep. I use the notification center of `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()` to receive wake notifications like so:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "onSystemWake:", name: NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification, object: nil)
```

My problem is the implementation of `onSystemWake:`. I use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code to query if there is internet connectivity when the system wakes:

```
@objc func onSystemWake(notif: NSNotification) {
    let status = internetReachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
    if status.value == NotReachable.value {
        // Internet not reachable, do some stuff.
    } else {
        // Internet reachable, do some other stuff.
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine when I'm at home and put my laptop into sleep and wake it again. However, if the laptop switches to another known WiFi during sleep (e.g. when I arrive at my university), the code above detects that there is *no* internet reachability when the laptop wakes from sleep at the new location - despite that there is actually a known WiFi available.

I assume that the cause of this is that the network connection is still in the process of being established when the system wake notification is received by my application.

I could delay my internet reachability check to occur *x* seconds after the system wake notification has been received, but this seems like a very bad solution as some combinations of laptops and networks may have longer connection times than others.

Is there a way to be notified when the network adapters (both wired and wireless) have finished their connection attempts?

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to claim what network is it! because maybe you are connected to a network which is a network! but its not connected to the internet!

for internet reachability i use the code below and it works fine for me on iOS!

```
        let domain: NSURL = NSURL(string : "http://google.com/")!
    let req : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: domain)
    req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let data = "\0"
    req.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (respons,data,error) in
            print(respons)
            if respons == nil
            {
\\ Internet is not Active!!
            }
            else
            {
\\ Internet is Active!!
                }
        }
```

The Above code is saying google means internet! if i can reach google.com it means I'm connected to some network anyway! but if not I'm not!

the problem is if you are using a network which is like a company network and the network isn't providing you an internet connection! the above code won't satisfy your needs! in that case and of course depend on your network you have to request something else! like the Router!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you misunderstood my question. I am not asking how to check for internet connectivity - that part is already working just fine using the reachability API. My problem is when to check for internet connectivity as the computer wakes from sleep. This is problematic as the connection still may be in the progress of being established when the wake notification is received.

Comment: maybe you can check lot of time